# Vim's (MVIM) Local Leader, BackSlash Only Beeps

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm new to VIM, using MacVim, and I'm trying to use Backslash as local leader. It seems like that is the default. If I do:

```
:let maplocalleader = "\\"
```

I just get a beep when I try to use local leader key `\`

If I do

```
:let maplocalleader = "-"
```

Then it works just fine. How do I get vim to stop beeping at me every time I try to use the backslash key?

Comment: backslash is default leader, you don't have to set it.

Comment: Yeah, I read that. But I'm not understanding why it's not working. The localleader command itself is working if the key is switched, but not by default, all I get is a beep. Any ideas?

Comment: How exactly are you trying to use it? Did you define a map using `<Leader>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\\\` is definitely wrong way to escape backslash. Inside *double* quotes it should be written as `"\\"`, inside *single* as `'\'`. `"\\\"` is an unfinished string `'\"'` (third backslash escapes double quote) thus it will show error after `:let` command.

The beep source is different: `\` key on its own is no-op unlike `-`. If you have mapping to `-a` and type just `-` then cursor will move to the previous line: it is a valid action. If you have mapping `\a` (or no mappings at all) and type `\` you will see beep because `\` is not a valid action. Only mappings like `\a` are valid thus they won’t beep.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Was able to get everything figured out based on the second part of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put that command in your vimrc. Leader and local leader commands to not affect commands that have already been parsed by vim.

Comment: From what I've read you have to use \\ and not just \ because \ is the escape character in Vimscript strings. So let maplocalleader = "\" is processed as let maplocalleader = ""

Comment: @user2229277 I realized what was happening with my original answer of `:let maplocalleader="\"`. This command errored and just used the default. Which just happens to be `\`. Can you try putting the command in your vimrc before plugins are loaded?

Comment: As Kent pointed out above the default leader is backslash. So I know I don't have to set it, I was just changing it to make sure it was working. When I keep it at the default of backslash, it just beeps at me. I'm unable to use that key and it's driving me nuts :/

Comment: @newUserNameHere `let maplocalleader="\"` is processed similar to `let maplocalleader="`, not as `let maplocalleader=""`. If you escape quote (backslash does escape it) you will get unfinished string, not something else.